# How to Create Nested Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

My dataset is: 
[image]

I want to organize the in the following json format:

```
data: {
    'year' : 2014,
    'year_data' : {
        'month' : 'January',
        'month_data' : {
            'day' : {
                '1' : 100,
                '2' : 200,
                '3' : 300,
                '4' : 400,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my approach:

```
function sheetData($data, $sheet) {
    echo "<pre>";
    $years = ['2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018'];
    $months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 
    'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    $x = 1; 
    $segment = 0;
    $segment_end = 11;
    $year_count = 0;
    $calc_years = [];
    $calc_months = [];
    while($x <= $sheet['numRows']) {
        $y = 3;
        if ($segment == $segment_end) { 
            $calc_months[$segment] = $months[$segment];
            $segment = 0;
            $calc_years[$year_count] = $years[$year_count];
            $year_count++;
        } else { 
            $calc_months[$segment] = $months[$segment];
            $segment++;
        }
        $col = 0;
        while($y <= $sheet['numCols']) {
            $cell = isset($sheet['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $sheet['cells'][$x][$y] : '';
            $calc_days[$col] =  $cell;
            $y++;
            $col++;
        }  
        $x++;
    }

    $data_year = array();
    $data_month = array();
    $data_day = array();
    $data_array = array();
    $count = 0;

    $count_years = count($calc_years);
    $count_months = count($calc_months);
    $count_days = count($calc_days);

    for ($p=0; $p < $count_years ; $p++) { 
      $data_array[$p]['year'] = $calc_years[$p];
      for ($q=0; $q < $count_months; $q++) {
        $data_array[$p]['year_data'][$q]['month'] = $calc_months[$q];
        for ($r=0; $r < $count_days; $r++) {
          $data_array[$p]['year_data'][$q]['month']['day'][$r] = $calc_days[$r];
        }
      }

    }

    var_dump($data_array);
}
```

I read the data from sheet and segmented as years, months and day in seperate arrays and lastly tried to write an array to populate the format i want. But
I am struggling to create nested array out of this. Tried in several ways but no solution. Any help?

Full Code link: [enter link description here](https://www.codepile.net/pile/YqAY9Yq6)

Sample : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NDpd0-sEMn47JDfhMagAjRnr_MemZttA

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are you loading your dataset? Can you show us your attempts at creating this array and share what problems you ran into? How can we help you fix your code if there is no code?

Comment: I will follow up El_Vanja's comment, by echoing the same. Stack Overflow is a question and answer community where people offer their time and knowledge to help others. The least you can do, is take the time to learn how to ask a good question, and to show your work so that others can feel as though they are genuinely helping you to learn, and not just someone doing your work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks @Crayons I am sorry for my short question. now I have updated my question. Pls have a look.

Comment: Can you give us a small sample of the `$sheet` contents (I know it's the data from the picture, but it'd be good to know exactly how that array is structured).

Comment: @El_Vanja pls check the question now. I have given the sample and full code. thanks

Comment: I literally meant a sample of `$sheet` (the variable). I don't know how you're loading the spreadsheet into php and how the resulting array is structured. I mean, I can assume, but I don't want to write an answer based on an assumption. A single element would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I find it's easiest to use the square bracket array notation in PHP:

```php
$array = [
  "data" => [
    "year" => 2014,
    "year_data" => [
      "month" => "January",
      "month_data" => [
        "day" => [
          "1" => 100,
          "2" => 200,
          "3" => 300,
          "4" => 400
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

You can then convert this array, into a JSON string like this:

```php
json_encode($array);
```

Comment: I highly doubt the OP is looking for a manual solution to building arrays, judging by the size of the dataset.

Comment: yes @crayons i am trying to do so but struggling on creating the nested array dynamically.

Comment: @El_Vanja Of course common sense tells me the OP wants to turn that dataset, into a JSON object. Alas, the OP failed to put the effort into asking a proper question, and so I elected to answer the only question the OP actually asked: 'how to create a nested array'.